# laravel ajax returnning the 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

This is my script

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#add').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/comments',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        message: $('#message').val(),
                    },
                    success: function(result){
                        jQuery('.alert').show();
                        jQuery('.alert').html(result.success);
                    }});
                });
            });
    </script>
```

My form

```
<form>
        @csrf
        @honeypot
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Enter your Comment/Review here:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control @if($errors->has('message')) is-invalid @endif" name="message" rows="3" id="message"></textarea>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Your Review/Comment is required.
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success text-uppercase" id="add">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

My Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all());
    // If guest commenting is turned off, authorize this action.
    // if (config('comments.guest_commenting') == false) {
    //     $this->authorize('create-comment', Comment::class);
    // }

    // Define guest rules if user is not logged in.
    // if (!auth()->check()) {
    //     $guest_rules = [
    //         'guest_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    //         'guest_email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
    //     ];
    // }

    // // Merge guest rules, if any, with normal validation rules.
    // $this->validate($request, array_merge($guest_rules ?? [], [
    //     'commentable_type' => 'required|string',
    //     'commentable_id' => 'required|string|min:1',
    //     'message' => 'required|string'
    // ]));

    $model = $request->commentable_type::findOrFail($request->commentable_id);

    $commentClass = config('comments.model');
    $comment = new $commentClass;

    if (!auth()->check()) {
        $comment->guest_name = $request->guest_name;
        $comment->guest_email = $request->guest_email;
    } else {
        $comment->commenter()->associate(auth()->user());
    }

    $comment->commentable()->associate($model);
    $comment->comment = $request->message;
    $comment->approved = !config('comments.approval_required');
    $comment->save();

    // if($request->ajax()) {
    //     return response()->json(['success'=>'Operation succed']);
    // }
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Operation Succeed']);

    //return redirect()->to(url()->previous() . '#comment-' . $comment->id);
}
```

This all code is returning the 500 Internal Server Error I dont know why !!!!
I tried fixing the meta code but still result is the same . Also tried fixing all the possible solutions found in the forums and other things but the result is same . Can anyone explain what is the problem and how to solve it

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 POST http://booksmandala.test/comments 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @BipinRegmi: "500 Internal Server Error" means there was an error *on the server*.  You need to find out what the error is before you can correct it.  Check your Laravel and/or PHP error logs.

Comment: I check there was no error

Comment: @BipinRegmi: That drastically limits what we can do to help.  Again, before addressing any error, one needs to see what the error is.  You are encouraged to tweak your PHP error reporting (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), tweak your Laravel error handling (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors), and of course also examine the response body from the AJAX operation in your browser's debugging tools for any helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the content of your error is what will help you debug your problem.

The first thing you should check is your `.env` file, search for the value of `APP_DEBUG` and set it to `true`. This will let Laravel display the content of your error directly to the browser.

You can also check the content of your Laravel log files in the `storage\logs` folder.

Lastly, be sure to check the Network tab of your browser inspector as your Ajax request and it's status/response will appear there.